# How to stop chrome.tabs.reload from resetting the extension icon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons, reload, browser-action

i am writing an extension which sets the extension-icon to an "active" one for a specific tab, but if i reload this tab by chrome.tabs.reload(id), the icon changes back to the default one.

Little code example:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    path: "img/icon_active.png",
    tabId: 1
});
chrome.tabs.reload(1); // <--- resets the icon to the default one, why?
```

I need to stop reload from resetting the tabs icon. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Is icon reset when user reloads the tab manually?

Comment: Yes it resets to default too, if the reload is done by pressing f5 or the reload button.

Comment: So it probably works as intended. Just change your code so that 'active' icon is being set every time desired tab [is updated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated).